# DJANGO_CELERY_BEAT access PeriodicTask from shared_task

Tags: django, celery, django-celery, django-celery-beat

In my project, I use [django celery beat](https://django-celery-beat.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) package to execute scheduled tasks. It works well but I have one case that I can't handle.

All the tasks have a `PeriodicTack` that schedules them.

So the following task:

```py
from celery import shared_task

@shared_task
def foo(**kwargs):
    # Here I can to things like this :
    whatever_method(kwargs["bar"])
```

Don't know if it is luck but it turns out that `kwargs` "points" to the [kwargs attribute](https://django-celery-beat.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/django-celery-beat.models.html#django_celery_beat.models.PeriodicTask.kwargs) of the `PeriodicTask` model.

**My question is :**

1. How can I access the `PeriodicTask` instance that made the task run ?
2. What if I have 2 `PeriodicTask` that use the same shared_task but with different schedules/parameters, will it find out which one was the source for that particular run ?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Maybe I should use `@app.task` decorator instead but not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found a way to do this.

As I said in the comment, making use of `@app.task` solves my needs.

I end up with a task like this :

```py
@app.task(bind=True)
def foo(self, **kwargs):
    # The information I personally need is in self properties, like so :
    desired_info = self.request.properties

    # Do whatever is needed with desired info...
    # Do whatever else ...
```

Where `app` is the Celery app as described in the [docs](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/django/first-steps-with-django.html#using-celery-with-django).

The `bind=True` is, as I understood, necessary to make the task having its own request and thus having access to `self` with information.